# I've read that burdock contact can cause irritation, where can I plant it?

Tags: planting

Where would be the best place to plant Burdock so that it won't irritate me when digging in the garden?

Comment: Burdock is normally considered a weed due to it's prickly seed heads.  Why would you want to plant it?

Comment: So I know what I'm going to be eating, since I haven't seen it near me (a low swampish area).

Comment: I would also highly recommend not planting burdock. In some places it may be illegal to do so (if it is on the banned noxious weed list in your state). If you want to grow it for the roots, I'm certain you can find a place where it is already growing and the owners will be happy to have you dig it out for them.

Comment: What should the list of requirements be before I start looking to dig it up?

Comment: I'd just ask. I don't have any burdock currently, but when I lived in a yard that had it, I would have been THRILLED if someone offered to dig it out for me. Seriously thrilled. If your community has a resale board or something similar, you could post there, offering to dig it up.

Comment: So I should put out an online ad for free?

Comment: a coder - It's worth a try!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Burdock does not cause irritation unless you are allergic/sensitive to it, which is rare.

This is a good article: http://www.gardenersnet.com/vegetable/burdock.htm

Comment: It irritates to me to pick the burrs off the dog ;)